# How to fix or investigate this AcquiaDevDesktop error during import

Tags: git, drupal-7, acquia

Got a new laptop, installed Acquia devDesktop, added my ssh key, refreshed Acquia Cloud sites, (for those unaware, Acquia devDesktop is just a lamp stack specific for Drupal)when I "Cloned dev site to local" i get the attached error.

I have googled around and have not found a reference to this error - Does anyone have any insight/assistance in resolving this?

I was able to clone the dev site to my local on my temporary laptop just two weeks ago without issue. **Any suggestions, assistance would be greatly appreciated**.

i took a shot and uninstall, then reinstalled, but receiving same error.  Rolled back to the version installed on my previous laptop, same error.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[Acquia mentions](https://support.acquia.com/hc/en-us/articles/360010938594-Changes-to-supported-libssh2-algorithms) it may use **[libgit2](https://libgit2.org/)** to communicate with Acquia Git repositories.

And `parent is not a directory` is more a libgit2 error message, as seen in [libgit2/libgit2sharp issue 846](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/846).

> The message does appear odd, I suspect it's as an effect of the implementation details for creating references.
>
> What this message seems to indicate is that there is some reference already there which is a prefix of the path leading up to the one we are trying to create. The Git system cannot cope with this, but we should be providing a much better error message.

So check if you have a tag or branch named "`release`" already in your repo.